# Как задать бесконечный цикл в telebot python

Tags: python, telebot, библиотека

Тестирую создание бота для телеграм import telebot на python, но столкнулся с одной проблемой, вообщем в боте есть кнопки как пример 'математика', под клавиатурой, и я создал функцию когда нажимая на кнопку происходит это

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    matem = types.KeyboardButton('Математика')
    geogr = types.KeyboardButton('География')
    himikal = types.KeyboardButton('Химия')
    markup.row(matem)
    markup.row(geogr, himikal)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, я бот <b>Cody</b>', parse_mode = 'html', reply_markup = markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, on_click)

def on_click(message):
    if message.text == 'Математика':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Веб-сайт математики откроется через пару секунд.')
        time.sleep(3)
        webbrowser.open('https://vk.com')
```

но дело в том что только 1 раз можно нажать на кнопку, чтобы открылся веб сайт, второй раз когда нажимаешь ничего не происходит, не могли бы вы помочь мне с этим?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант это открывать браузер в отдельном потоке:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    matem = types.KeyboardButton('Математика')
    geogr = types.KeyboardButton('География')
    himikal = types.KeyboardButton('Химия')
    markup.row(matem)
    markup.row(geogr, himikal)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, я бот <b>Cody</b>', parse_mode = 'html', reply_markup = markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, on_click)

def thr():
    webbrowser.open('https://vk.com')

def on_click(message):
    if message.text == 'Математика':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Веб-сайт математики откроется через пару секунд.')
        time.sleep(3)            
        th = threading.Thread(target=thr)
        th.start()
```

Comment: Так себе вариант, а если мне не нужно к примеру открыть браузер, а просто текст, как здесь сделать чтобы текст отправялйся при каждой нажатии